# LinearLayout width in RecyclerView.ViewHolder and DataBinding

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, android-databinding

I happened to run into one little problem. In my project I use `DataBinding` and `RecyclerView` to bind data to `ViewHolder`s and display it. Problem is: on first bind `TextView` width is much larger than text in it (`layout_width`is set to `wrap_content`).

Here is my XML code.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/messageBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft='@{same?@dimen/four:@dimen/zero}'
            android:paddingRight='@{(mess.isMine &amp;&amp; same)?@dimen/four:@dimen/zero}'
            android:text='@{mess.message,default = "Message"}'
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0.35"
            android:gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text='@{Utils.parseMillsToHoursAndMins(mess.date,true,true),default = "14:22"}'
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

In onBindViewHoder I simply call holder.binding.setVariable(..), so nothing special.

I attached two images with results. Fist one - first binding. Second one - after scrolling up and down.

[image: First]
[image: Second]

### Update. Binding code

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final BindingViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.mess, data.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
    }
```

### Update 2. onCreateViewHolder() code

```
 @Override
public BindingViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    switch (viewType) {
        case TYPE_ITEM: {
            return new MessageItemViewHolder(DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.rv_item_message_item, parent, false).getRoot());
        }
        case TYPE_HEADER: {
            return new MessageHeaderViewHolder(DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.rv_item_message_header, parent, false).getRoot());
        }
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Inaccepteble view type");
    }
}
```

Yea, there is actually 2 view types.

Comment: Have you tried calling `binding.executePendingBindings()` after setting the variable in onBindViewHolder()?

Comment: @GeorgeMount Yes, it's done already

Comment: I don't think that this is an issue with data binding specifically, but with RecyclerView. It seems to be giving different sizes to your measure and layout depending on which other items have been added/scrolled and rebinding may be a factor as well. I would try using `match_parent` for the width of the LinearLayout and add a `<Space>` to consume the remaining space (first item in the LinearLayout).

Comment: @GeorgeMount I already submited issue. And unfortunately your solution isn't viable for me. These `TextView`s are just a part of layout and if something there will be `match_parent` it will ruin all.

Comment: @Ekalips could you show us the adapter code as well?

Comment: @OlegOsipenko Sure, I updated the post

Comment: @Ekalips and 'onCreateViewHolder()` also, please

Comment: @OlegOsipenko done